# Get values from multiple POJO using Hibernate Criteria

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-criteria

Table A columns

```
Id,Quantity,Name
```

Table B Columns

```
Id,Order_Date,A_Id
```

Does anyone know how to write Criteria query to get values from multiple table/POJO

```
Select a.*,b.Order_Date from A a,B b where a.Id=b.A_Id
```

so final result must be like this `Id,Quantity,Name,A_Id`.

I am just start learning Hibernate and I only know to get values from one table/POJO

```
 Criteria crit = this.getSession().createCriteria(A.class);
```

Comment: can you show me the mapping of A and B POJOs ?

Comment: just assume the table columns value is same as for POJOs

Comment: Anyone want to help me

Comment: Dear I am asking about whether there is any one-to-one mapping or something ???

Comment: of course got mapping. B is many to one A

Comment: hope the answer helps !!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ways of doing this as follow :

**1. Returning POJO of A with inner join B.**

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(A.class);
criteria.setFetchMode("b",FetchMode.JOIN);
criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("id",a.id));
A returnObjA = criteria.uniqueResult();
```

The above is when you want to have whole POJO rather than just few entities of the POJO.

**2. Applying Projection :**

Let us say if you want only id of B.

```
ProjectionList p1=Projections.projectionList();
p1.add(Projections.property("balias.id"));
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(A.class);
criteria.createAlias("b","balias");
criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("id",a.id));
criteria.setProjection(p1);
List<Long> bidList = criteria.listResult();
```

Also for further reference you can go through the following link.
http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/tutorial.html